# What is the largest aircraft ever successfully flown and landed with no pilot on board?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, autopilot, remote-pilot

I'm not sure if this belongs here or on the drone site.

What is the largest aircraft (not spacecraft) that has completed an entire flight, including takeoff and no- or minimal-damage landing, either on autopilot or by remote control (or a combination of the two), with no person on board the aircraft controlling it?

I'm interested in the largest by any measure (mass, wingspan, length).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "largest"? Mass, wingspan, length, ...?

Comment: Need to define "completed" I think - does that require a no-damage landing?

Comment: @MikeBrockington yes, I was thinking of a no-damage landing, so a crash test isn't quite what I was thinking of.

Comment: A ‘good’ landing has been defined as a landing after which most parts of the aircraft are still where they’re supposed to be.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Following along on the wingspan idea, the [Helios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AeroVironment_Helios_Prototype) had a 247 foot wingspan.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

Depending if you go by wingspan or mass, that would either be a [Boeing 720 flown by remote control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Impact_Demonstration) for a full-up crash test (investigating how jet fuel fires start in a crash), the (slightly longer, similar span) 727-200 used in a similar test in 2012, or the Soviet Buran spacecraft orbiter, which flew [a single orbital flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_(spacecraft)) (boosted by the Energia core rocket, since their version had no high-thrust rocket engines of its own) completely under remote or computer control (uncrewed).

Comment: I wouldn't really call those a "takeoff and landing." OP also specified not spacecraft. +1 though. Those are probably the biggest remotely controlled things that flew.

Comment: @TomMcW The 720 was actually flown a number of times on remote with pilots aboard to verify control could be maintained -- though I don't believe they attempted a landing with remote control.  Also, Buran could be and was on at least one occasion flown from the one airport to another with the aid of "strap-on" jet engines -- though that wasn't done by remote/computer control, in my eyes, that makes Buran an aircraft with orbital capability rather than "just" a spacecraft.

Comment: I’m surprised modern airplanes are not tested with remote control first.

Comment: @Michael It's a LOT harder to land something that big from a distance of a couple miles, and put it on a runway, than it is to do it from inside the cockpit.  Ask anyone who flies both R/C and full size, R/C is harder.  Given the cost of modern aircraft prototypes (billion dollars and up-up-up), they'll fly first with pilots for a long time yet unless designed from ground up as RPV or autonomous.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: I’m wondering if remote control with proper cameras and instrumentation would really be harder. You could even integrate it into a simulator (assuming you can get the input/output latencies low enough).

Comment: @Michael I see two issues.  First, people who spend a lot of time in a simulator may become conditioned to "let it crash" where they'd take more effective recovery measures if their butt is in the cockpit -- and second, there will inevitably be issues with field of view (can't rise out of the seat and look out a side window to see if #1 is still on the pylon when the instruments go crazy, for instance) and feedback (simulators can't motion simulate extreme maneuvers).

Comment: @Michael sounds like good material for a whole new question. Feel free to ask it.

Comment: @Michael, military drones may be flown from an office thousands of miles away, but they're landed by someone standing beside the runway holding a controller.

Comment: @Michael Plane 'testing' is mostly done in simulators and with CFD. When you get pilots in the plane for the first time, they don't just take off and do a circuit and hope it lands. They taxi, they fast taxi, they rotate, none of this risky leaving the ground yet, all to prove the results of the CFD and simulators. It's quite well proved by the time you first get fresh air under the tires. The rest of the speed/altitude envelope is explored in similar incremental fashion.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Still looks like an unnecessary risk when you could remote control it. With remote control you can also test until destruction (or close to). Would also be interesting to test old planes before their retirement until destruction to see how much life they’d actually still have left in them.

Comment: Another contender could be the boeing 727-200 used for a crash experiment in 2012. It would be slightly longer than the 720 in the answer. Might be good to add that, perhaps?

Comment: I'll do so, thanks @kirgod.

Comment: @ZeissIkon The Space Shuttle Orbiter was frequently flown from one airport to another. This was done with the aid of a strap-on Boeing 747. :)

Answer (score 12):

If you go by wingspan, I nominate the [Boeing Condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Condor): At 205 ft (62 m) it is in the class of the Boeing 777-300ER or the A340-600, but at less than 10 tons take-off mass it is a minnow compared to them or the Buran. Its length of 20 m puts it a shade ahead of the flying wings by Paul McCready.

Here is what Wikipedia has to say about the [Condor](https://www.boeing.com/history/products/condor-unmanned-aerial-vehicle.page):

> In 1989, the Condor set the world piston-powered aircraft altitude record of 67,028 ft (20,430 m) and was the first aircraft to fly a fully automated flight from takeoff to landing and also setting an unofficial endurance world record in 1988 by flying continuously for more than 50 hours

Since you ask for the largest aircraft, my money is on the Condor.

Comment: One or more of the solar "airsats" likely has a larger span than Condor -- and Solar Impulse 2, with "the span of a 747" is in process of conversion to fly autonomously -- at least report, they still carried a pilot for takeoff and landing, but expect to eliminate that need soon.

Comment: Not as big, so not an answer, but it's worth mentioning that the GlobalHawk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_RQ-4_Global_Hawk) is production UAV with 130.9 ft wingspan.

Comment: I had to read that 4 times to see that it wasn't designed by "Paul McCartney". I thought "went from a Beatle to an aircraft designer? Wow!"

Comment: @FreeMan -- seems natural enough after he was in Wings.

Comment: Ooh, good point, @PeteBecker!

Comment: When and how did this thing fly without a pilot? Maybe you want to include the relevant parts of the linked article in this post, if the article goes offline (and Wikipedia asks for money so often that I start to believe that it eventually will be offline)

Comment: @ZeissIkon - "they still carried a pilot for takeoff and landing" - ok, I get how the pilot can get _off_ the plane so the thing can fly itself, but how does one get back _on_ to take over for the landing?

Comment: @davidbak During the "backup piloted" test flights, the pilot was onboard from before engine start to after engine shutdown.  On the actual crash test flight, takeoff and "landing" were both handled by the remote control system.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the [Zeppelin LZ 24 "L3"](http://www.aircraftinvestigation.info/airplanes/Zeppelin_LZ24_L3.html) of the Imperial German Navy. It had a length of 158m and a volume of 22,470 m3.

[image: Zeppelin LZ 24]

Now admittedly it was not *intentionally* flown without a pilot on board. On 17 February 1915 L3 was escorting a German ship heading for Africa, but after an engine failure compounded by strong headwinds and lack of fuel the captain was forced to put it down on the island of [Fanø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan%C3%B8), Denmark (just north of the then current border with Germany)

> The wind was so strong it blew the airship, now
> unmanned but with engines still running, out to sea.

Eventually it crashed (but so did the Boeing 720 mentioned elsewhere!). Kapitänleutnant Hans Fritz and his crew were detained for the rest of the war. This airship had the distinction of participating in the first air raid on England on 19 January 1915, killing two residents of [Great Yarmouth](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/tag/l3/).

Comment: Fits the header, but not the actual text, of original question --